# On Cell edit of react-bootstrap-table, in dropdown I want the unique index of selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a cell edit functionality in which I am using `editable={ { type: 'select', options: { values} } }`. After selecting a value, I want its unique index value as options have common values. Is there any way to do it?

Here is the Code of Table:

```
    <BsTable
                        errorMessage={ '' }
                        loading={ false }
                        options={ STATIC_TABLE_OPTIONS }
                        data={ this.state.updatedSteps }
                        rowsCount={ this.state.updatedSteps.length }
                        fetchInfo={ {
                            dataTotalSize: this.state.updatedSteps.length
                        } }
                        cellEdit={ cellEditProp }
                        headerContainerClass="my-header-class"
                        headerStyle={ {
                            fontSize: 'smaller'
                        } }
                        bordered={ false }
                    >
                        <Column dataField="idx" isKey hidden />
                        <Column dataField="selectedBusinessStep"
                            width="15%"
                            editable={ { type:    'select',
                                options: { values: arrBizStep }
                            } }
                        > </BsTable>
```

And in the cellEditProp, my code is:

```
const cellEditProp = {
        mode:          'click',
        blurToSave:    true,
        afterSaveCell: ( row, cellName, cellValue ) => {
            this.props.editCombinationHandler( row );
        }
    };
```

When I change the value from dropDown which is located in:

```
<Column dataField="selectedBusinessStep"
                        width="15%"
                        editable={ { type:    'select',
                            options: { values: arrBizStep }
                        } }
```

I get the row, cellName and cellValue in afterSaveCell function, which is in cellEditProp mentioned above. is there any way to get the index of the selected item of dropdown `<Column dataField="selectedBusinessStep"`.
Please let me know if you need more discription?

Comment: You must provide some code to show use what have you achieved yourself and then we can help.

Comment: Hi Haniis - I have provided the code in the question, hope it is clear to you, else please ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the index of selected item in SELECT dropdown.

```
const cellEditProp = {
    mode: 'click',
    blurToSave: true,
    afterSaveCell: handleChange
};
```

And handleChange

```
function handleChange(oldValue, newValue, row, column) {
  let indexOfSelectedItem = -1;
  column.editor.options.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (newValue === item.value) {
      indexOfSelectedItem = idx;
    }
  });
  if (indexOfSelectedItem > -1) {
    console.log(indexOfSelectedItem);
  }

  // indexOfSelectedItem <<<< 

}
```

I have made this simple demo with react-bootstrap-table-2, but the same logic can be used to previous version as well. Hope this helped you to resolve the issue.

Click on price to edit and the check the console output:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-next-with-editable-price-tgy0y

Comment: In react-bootstrap-table - function `handleChange` takes these parameters - `( row, cellName, cellValue, props )` . the params suggested by you `(oldValue, newValue, row, column)` may be the part of *react-bootstrap-table 2*. In this table, 4th paramater of function is `props`, which gives its `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` instead of  `column.editor.options`. 

Also I have dulicated options, means an option in the dropdown can be multiple times. its not a unique options list. So the code written in `forEach` will not gonna work, please suggest now.

Comment: You are right about `react-bootstrap-table`, it pass only `(row, cellName, cellValue, props)`, so in that case you have to implement your own customFieldEditor. Look at this example from `react-bootstrap-table` https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-with-editable-price-vdznh (Line 140 allow you to get the index of select box).